Shared element transition while using Destination library - Compose Android
Destination this library is life saver for maintaining screens in compose as it removed lots of boiler plate but now i want to use the shared element transition with it and i am struggling to build it as what should i pass in the parameter.
We can pass string, boolean, serialized class but what is required to be passed down to next screen for transition animation

You can pass Int, String, Double, or Float or any class as long as rememberSharedContentState(key: Any) keys match in sharedElement or sharedBounds in both screens.
But using unique keys are suggested by google

When working with complex shared elements, it is a good practice to
create a key that is not a string, because strings can be error prone
to match. Each key must be unique for matches to occur. For example,
in Jetsnack we have the following shared elements:

data class SnackSharedElementKey(
    val snackId: Long,
    val origin: String,
    val type: SnackSharedElementType
)

enum class SnackSharedElementType {
    Bounds,
    Image,
    Title,
    Tagline,
    Background
}


@Composable
fun SharedElementUniqueKey() {
    // ...
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .sharedElement(
                        rememberSharedContentState(
                            key = SnackSharedElementKey(
                                snackId = 1,
                                origin = "latest",
                                type = SnackSharedElementType.Image
                            )
                        ),
                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedVisibility
                    )
            )
            // ...
}

I made a sample with String keys that transitions from LazyColumn to HorizontalPager with navigation but as you can see neither screen are dependent of NavController.

@Composable
private fun DetailsScreen(
    snack: SnackItem,
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit,
) {

    var selectedIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(listSnacks.indexOf(snack).coerceAtLeast(0))
    }
    with(sharedTransitionScope) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
            initialPage = selectedIndex,
            pageCount = {
                listSnacks.size
            }
        )

        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            pageSpacing = 16.dp
        ) { page ->

            selectedIndex = page
            val currentSnack = listSnacks[page]

            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember {
                            MutableInteractionSource()
                        },
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        onClick("home")
                    }
            ) {
                Image(
                    painterResource(id = currentSnack.image),
                    contentDescription = currentSnack.description,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedElement(
                            sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = "image-$selectedIndex"),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope
                        )
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Text(
                    currentSnack.name, fontSize = 38.sp,
                    modifier =
                    Modifier
                        .sharedBounds(
                            sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = "text-$selectedIndex"),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope,
                        )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HomeScreen(

    scrollState: LazyListState,
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    animatedContentScope: AnimatedContentScope,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit,
) {

    var isDetailSelected by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    with(sharedTransitionScope) {
        Column {

            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text("Title")
                },
                backgroundColor = Color.Black,
                contentColor = Color.White,
                modifier = if (isDetailSelected) Modifier
                else Modifier.renderInSharedTransitionScopeOverlay()
            )
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
                state = scrollState,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(listSnacks) { index, item ->
                    Row(
                        Modifier.clickable(
                            interactionSource = remember {
                                MutableInteractionSource()
                            },
                            indication = null
                        ) {
                            isDetailSelected = true
                            onClick("details/$index")
                        }
                    ) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        Image(
                            painterResource(id = item.image),
                            contentDescription = item.description,
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .sharedElement(
                                    sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = "image-$index"),
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope
                                )
                                .size(120.dp)
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        Text(
                            item.name, fontSize = 18.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                                .sharedBounds(
                                    sharedTransitionScope.rememberSharedContentState(key = "text-$index"),
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedContentScope
                                )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

